# How do you insulate the peak of cathedral ceiling?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic

I am converting an unconditioned attic to living space, and I will insulate the cathedral ceiling with mineral wool batts. I have seen a million articles, Q&A pieces, and videos that tell me how to build baffles running from the soffit to vents near the peak of the roof, fine. I have seen no advice on how you finish the deal with some system of horizontal insulation along the peak of my proposed ceiling. I know I need to leave some air space along the ridge to facilitate all the air flowing through those baffles exiting through my vents. Insulate below that "master baffle" running along the ridge?

Comment: What are your ground snow loads like? You may be better off using an unvented roof configuration...

Comment: I'm in Chicago, so... but that ship has sailed: I am committed to the approach I described for better or worse!

Comment: Out of curiosity, how will you be getting the batts in place?

Comment: My thought is to just run the baffles all the way to the ridge, but that's obviously not going to work for you. How about providing some sort of drawing so we've got an idea of what you're up against, because I'm a bit stumped by your quandary.